# Sails.js : File was changed on disk

Tags: node.js, windows-8.1, sails.js, webstorm

I use WebStorm for a Sails.js project.

When I start my server WebStorm says me that "File was changed on disk" and changes my file to a previous version.

I use Windows 8.1.

How to overwrite the files on disk ? Save don't change anything.

Comment: How do you start your server? through WebStorm or command line?

Comment: I use sails lift or forever start app.js

Comment: since I used forever I have this problem. I uninstalled it and have the problem now.

Comment: what file are changed? it it's on `.tmp`, or some layout that use `<!--SCRIPTS-->` so no problems.

Comment: First time I do not delete <!--SCRIPTS--> in my layout. Why does sails delete some lines between <!--SCRIPTS--> ? Thx for your help.